# SSH via multiple hosts or bastions

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

Currently, as per normal procedure, we have a bastion server in each public subnet within a cloud network and we attempt to access it via the following config -

```
Host webserverA
    User myuser
    Hostname 192.168.1.10
    ForwardAgent yes
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh -q bastionA nc %h %p
    IdentityFile ~/webserver.pem
```

Is there a way for me to extend this model to having another bastion server?

BastionB -> BastionA -> WebserverA ?

The reasoning is that I'd like to treat this as a Chain of Trust. Remove something when a rather bad event occurs.

By CoT I mean, if a set of users leaves, we can change the first set of keys so that we can block their further access.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "chain of trust" part.

Comment: @grawity - basically in plain terms, pull a key out to block a whole set of unwanted users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Method 1 – onion (nested tunnels)

With OpenSSH 7.3 and later:

```
Host webserverA
    ProxyJump bastionA,bastionB
```

The same via command line:

```
$ ssh -J bastionA,bastionB webserverA
```

Alternatively (also with 7.3; *don't* mix this and above):

```
Host webserverA
    ProxyJump bastionB

Host bastionB
    ProxyJump bastionA
```

With older versions – mostly identical (but doesn't automatically copy options like `ssh -v`):

```
Host webserverA
    ProxyCommand ssh bastionB -W %h:%p

Host bastionB
    ProxyCommand ssh bastionA -W %h:%p
```

This method initiates all connections locally, setting up a `ssh -W` tunnel to each step. Therefore authentication happens locally (ForwardAgent and GSSAPIDelegateCredentials are not required) and your local `.ssh/config` applies to each step as well. Server-side, only basic "TCP forwarding" support is needed, same as when using `-W` or `-L`.

However, each layer adds extra overhead, since it ends up carrying SSH in SSH in SSH in SSH.

Note that each host, except for the outermost one, lists a ProxyCommand through the server immediately before it. If you had 3 servers, you would use [webserverA via bastionC], [bastionC via bastionB], and [bastionB via bastionA].

#### Method 2 – hop by hop

```
Host webserverA
    ProxyCommand ssh bastionA -A ssh bastionB -W %h:%p
```

This method initiates connections hop by hop, running `ssh` on each hop to connect to the next one. Therefore a ssh-agent and `ForwardAgent` must be enabled (or `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials` if you use Kerberos); any other special `.ssh/config` settings must be copied to all bastion hosts.

On the other hand, it incurs less protocol overhead (max. two layers at every step).

(Edit: added `-A` to always request agent forwarding.)

Comment: Note that `ssh <host> -W` is functionally nearly identical to `ssh <host> nc ...`, except not depending on any external tools. (Instead it uses the same 'tunnel' feature as `ssh -L` or `ssh -D`.)